# ios load large file use memory mapping failed

Tags: ios

use below methods to mapping a large file failed.

```
NSData *mappedData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:self.videoPath options:NSDataReadingMappedAlways error:&error];
```

or map:

```
int fd = open([path fileSystemRepresentation], O_RDONLY);
struct stat statbuf;
if (fstat(fd, &statbuf) == -1) {
    close(fd);
    return nil;
}

void *mappedFile;
mappedFile = mmap(0, statbuf.st_size, PROT_READ, MAP_FILE|MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
close(fd);
if (mappedFile == MAP_FAILED) {
    NSLog(@"Map failed, errno=%d, %s", errno, strerror(errno));
    return nil;
}

// Create the NSData
NSData *mappedData = [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:mappedFile length:statbuf.st_size freeWhenDone:NO];`
```

memory mapping failed , mappedData load whole file to RAM.

why failed? any other suggestion?

Comment: Can you post the error massage ?

Comment: Why not use NSFileHandler instead to for file loading. It is a quite optimized way to handle files in Obj C

Comment: dataWithContentsOfFile error return nil, use mmap mappedFile!= MAP_FAILED

Comment: use nsdata upload video to facebook, Could NSFileHandler convert to NSData?

Comment: Yes shall i add the code for getting a file using NSfileManager. You can optimize it depending on whether you need the whole file on memory

Comment: I have added the answer. I dont exactly understand your requirement but if what you need is getting a file to NSdata then you can use my answer. If you fine my answer helpful please up vote and mark as the answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    NSString *applicationDirectory = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[fileManager URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject]];

    NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", applicationDirectory, fileNameWithExtension];

   // NSData *fileData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
NSData *fileData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath options:NSDataReadingMappedAlways error:&error];
```

You can get a file to memory only using NsData. But You can use NSfileHandler if you need to cache read the file while not loading the whole thing to memory at once. Since it seems a file is a video file i prefer you buffer it using NSfilehandler.

Edited: + dataWithContentsOfFile:options:error: can be used in order to save memory you can use NSDataReadingMappedAlways is files to be mapped always or NSDataReadingMappedIfSafe to be safe. Refer to https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: thank you for your help. if i divide the whole file to some small blocks. upload video will failed. so i want to load file map to memory  to protect memory usage

Comment: I am sure you can use nsfilehandler class to handle the scenario. just check the documentation. can you give me the link to facebook file upload api calls

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2011/08/04/how-to--use-the-graph-api-to-upload-a-video--ios/

Comment: it seems its quite straight forward.. You will have to get the file NSData inorder to update send a upload request alone with the parameter values.

Comment: ye, now ,the memory-mapping didn't work. if load large file, app will   receive memory warning. i have no idea

Comment: i had try this method, but fileData load whole file data into memory

Comment: look the first solution in my question. i don't know why  NSDataReadingMappedAlways didn't work . is any other property should set to enable memory-map?

Comment: the NSDataReadingMappedAlways worked when get rid of Facebook SDK. i think it's facebook SDB BUG. thank you!

Comment: oh ok.. If you find any answer share it.. :)

Comment: ye,i modify facebook SDK, use [request setHTTPBodyStream] instead of [request setHTTPBody], read http body from tmp file.